# Why trigger name is showing some object name

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have some trigger in a table but the trigger name is showing some object name instead of original trigger name:

```
select * from user_triggers where table_name='NVT_VEHICLE';
```

*Trigger name:*

```
BIN$j1ygh/CFFDXgVWVB5LsGMg==$1
BIN$j1ygh/CEFDXgVWVB5LsGMg==$1
NVT_LOG_TRIG
```

Comment: How to solve that error and how i will get previous name which i created

Answer (score 1):

These weird names are the name of the objects which are dropped by the user. You can get the original names of the objects from a table: `USER_RECYCLEBIN`

`USER_RECYCLEBIN` displays information about the recycle bin owned by the current user.

It contains `ORIGINAL_NAME` and `OBJECT_NAME` of the recycled objects.

In your case, you can try this query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    USER_RECYCLEBIN
WHERE
    NAME IN (
        'BIN$j1ygh/CFFDXgVWVB5LsGMg==$1',
        'BIN$j1ygh/CEFDXgVWVB5LsGMg==$1'
    );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: When i apply this query this is showing no data found.

Comment: Can you please tell me why this is showing this type of name???

Comment: Because these objects are deleted and oracle maintains it in recycle bin until and unless recycle bin is purged. You can get more information from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25494_01/tables011.htm)

Comment: This trigger is not deleted when i open this object name then this is showing the code.

Comment: create or replace TRIGGER "BIN$j1ygh/CCFDXgVWVB5LsGMg==$1" AFTER UPDATE of route_status ON "NVT_VEHICLE"
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW
declare
rtname varchar2(100);
BEGIN

select route_no||'['||src_location||'->'||dest_location||']' into rtname from hdc_source_dest_map where route_no=:old.route_no and rownum=1;
  Insert into hul_route(vehicle_no,route_no,route_status,route_id,route_name,route_time,sys_time)
  values (:old.vehicle_no,:old.route_no,:old.route_status,:old.route_id,rtname,:old.route_time,sysdate);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END;

Comment: Please look into the above trigger it is showing like that.But when i create i created in a name.This is convert automatically

Comment: Yes, It's DDL is maintained in the database. Just name is changed by Oracle. You can read the link which I have shared to get more idea about it